# Braintree disputes/chargeback card not working

Tags: braintree-sandbox

I am using the Braintree payment processor. I have been working on the integration of disputes.
I have configured ngrok to receive the webhooks on my local environment.

The card `4023898493988028` which will create a chargeback on a settled transaction, creates the transaction but it doesn't invoke the webhook for the dispute. I do not receive the webhook for the dispute as well.

Is there any workaround you know that has worked for you or that can help me. That will be so much helpful.

I want to know if I am missing any setting configurations or if there is any workaround to this situation.